# Acceptable to answer your own question when there is already a good answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

Am I right to be annoyed by this and is it appropriate to flag this answer?

I answered this question ([Unable to set the lookup with values on Entity form with lookup data from caller form in MS Dynamics CRM 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555079/unable-to-set-the-lookup-with-values-on-entity-form-with-lookup-data-from-caller/30586287?noredirect=1#comment49278274_30586287)) with a comprehensive answer that resolved the problem with the code in question.

The questioner waited the requisite two days and posted an answer which consisted of only a link and accepted the answer. I've invested time in formulating and typing out an answer that even the asker (in a comment) said was useful. If there was a better answer I wouldn't think anything of it - that is how we all improve - but it isn't. I could even understand if the asker rewrote my answer to something better - but it is just a link.

Comment: @Nicknow: I gave you an upvote to thank you for taking the trouble for answering out of my goodness. You did not understand the question hence I cannot use your answer. Read the question again and read the link I posted that is what I wanted. Your answer is not right sorry. Take it easy and do'nt take it personal. We are sharing information here on this forum and helping our community.

Comment: I've read your revised answer and it still isn't clear how the answer is related to the question _"I am not able to set the Approver lookup/Name: bch_signingauthority with ID being passed in via query string. Can you please help and suggest me how to go about doing this as I am fairly new to CRM Dynamics 2011."_  In addition, it still doesn't answer the question of HOW - it is just a description of the problem. At a minimum add your final working code for others to see.

Comment: take a look at the final working code added.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is much more usable now and will live within Stackoverflow (instead of an external link that may disappear.) I would also recommend revising your question to make it clearer to future readers the specific problem you needed to solve.

Comment: Worse can happen... like the OP first downvoting your answer and getting offended if you tell him they aren't being reasonable, then, realizing it's correct, copy&pasting it into a new one and accepting it just to avoid proving you correct.

Comment: I have answered my [own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662386/having-trouble-with-webmock-not-stubbing-correctly) after someone has helped me. The first answer helped guide me, but I detailed all my work in _my_ answer. I also gave the first person credit. I think it is a case-by-case thing, and in your case, you are right.

Comment: Has the OP's answer been deleted due to a downvote storm from people linked from this question?

Comment: People do odd things. I once had my answer accepted, and a year later the OP provided their own answer and unaccepted mine, accepting his own (which was not substantially different from mine)!

Comment: @jwg: No. Though it was downvoted, it was not deleted by the OP, but by Martjin, as the review-queue probably suggested.

Comment: According to the SO, a user should accept if the answer was helpful or useful. SO does not stipulate an accepted answer provide 100% of the coding solution. I think some new users won't accept a helpful answer that leads them to a solution or that helps them to recognize where their problem is. I just dealt with this -- led a poster to a solution. But he's a repeat offender for accepting a lot of help, but not accepting an answer. I assume he doesn't understand that a helpful answer should be accepted, especially when no one else is engaging on the question.

Comment: @Ruruboy: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: It looks like because of this meta post people have massively downvoted the questioner.

Comment: I appreciate the quality of discussions and collaboration going on here in StackOverflow. Being a user who just became active, this is enthralling compared to other Q&A sites like Quora. It's sad to see so many downvotes to the original question though.

Comment: How many upvotes did your answer have before you post here on meta?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> Am I right to be annoyed by this

I certainly am! It's very poor form on the OP's part. If they could answer their own question, there was no need to wait before doing so (the two days is for *accepting* the answer, you can *post* the answer at the same time as the question if you like).

> is it appropriate to flag this answer?

Yes: as it stands, it doesn't even really *qualify* as an answer (see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731))

---

However, to answer your title question:

> Acceptable to answer your own question when there is already a good answer?

Yes, it is, **as long as you have something to add**. Had the OP solved the issue independently (or even by building on your answer) and *come up with a good answer*, that would have been fair enough (although a credit to whoever set them on the path is always appreciated).

Comment: Well, you ninja'd the one important point I wanted to make here into your answer as I posted, so get an upvote.

Comment: The key here is that the asker's self-answer was of poor quality, regardless of whether there was already a high-quality answer. If the asker's self-answer was also of good quality, then it would have been appropriate for the asker to accept their own question. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: @Kevin yes, that would have been fine

Answer (score 17):

It is the OP's prerogative to decide which answer helped him or her. If the OP didn't find your answer useful then it shouldn't have been the accepted answer. This applies even if it wasn't your fault, or if it was definitely the OP's fault that your answer wasn't understood.  If the OP had to do separate research to get a solution, it was entirely appropriate for he or she to post the results of that research, and accept the answer.

This is completely independent of which answer was high quality or low quality. If your answer is of high quality, it should be rewarded by upvotes from other people. If the OP's answer is of low quality, it could be sanctioned by downvotes, or improved by comments and edits.

I understand that you are upset, but what you are suggesting basically implies that a 'jury' should decide whether the OP is allowed to select the answer which they thought helped them, or if they are too stupid to make that decision. This completely removes the purpose of answer acceptance.

Note that you could post a similar question with a high quality answer which you then accept, to help those who have the same problem in future.

An exception to the above would be if the OP had plagiarized your answer to steal rep. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. It is always acceptable to answer your own question, unless the question has been closed.

**Is it acceptable to answer a question badly?** Yes, but get ready for downvotes, close votes, etc. as appropriate. Whether the answerer also asked the question or not is irrelevant here - the answer should be judged on its own merits.

**Is it acceptable to answer a question when there's already a good answer?** Yes. Just because there's a good answer doesn't mean there isn't another good answer. Or bad answer, but again bad answers get dealt with in other ways.

**Is it acceptable to accept your own answer when there's already a good answer?** Yes. Good answers get upvotes, and the answer that the asker feels like accepting gets accepted. Whether you like it or not, the one special privilege that the asker gets is indicating which answer they choose to accept, *for any reason they choose*. The asker didn't gain any rep from posting and accepting his answer. He wished to indicate that as far as he is concerned your answer didn't answer his question, and that something else did. Nor did you lose anything by his accepting his own answer - he could equally just have abandoned the question. Instead he decided to share some information that he believed to be helpful, which has now been banished from the site by the meta effect by the looks of it.

**Are you right to be annoyed?**
Probably somewhat, hard to tell now most of the evidence has been removed from the eyes of lesser mortals. But how the asker handled the situation, interacted with you, waited for two days before posting an answer, etc. etc. and how that made you feel should not affect the judgement of whether his answer is good (no idea), or whether he has the right to post it (yes) and accept it (yes).

Comment: This expresses a similar sentiment to my answer but is much more clearly expressed, thanks!

Comment: @jwg Actually I think yours is pretty clear too. Didn't mean to be simply paraphrasing your answer, but I guess in the end it came close to that... Anyway, as I think someone said "Just because there's a good answer doesn't mean there isn't another good answer" ;)